# Mac data Backup-ped via SAMBA instead AFP: is it a bad thing?

Tags: mac-osx, samba, afp

i've a QNAP Nas, but at the moment the AFP protocol seems to be bugged. I've an office with 5 mac who saves data into a Mac Server. I want to backup data via Samba protocol to the Qnap Nas Server EXT4 server. May is this a bad thing ? Samba will mantain full compatibility with Mac ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Samba/SMB/CIFs will work just fine for backing up individual files it's not ideal for backing up your fully system. However some QNAP NAS boxes support OSX's native backup system 'Time Machine', there's a few hoops to jump through and it may make sense to update your NAS to the latest firmware but when Time Machine works it's lovely, really hands-off and lets you restore to 'bare metal' really easily - [HERE](http://wiki.qnap.com/wiki/How_to_setup_your_QNAP_NAS_with_Apple_Time_Machine)'s some instructions on how to make your NAS (if it supports this) work.

Comment: I was about to add an answer that included the warning that you can't back up the system for restore from SAMBA due to permission/owner incompatibilities between filesystems unless the SAMBA system were hosting some kind of disk image that is mounted, formatted HPFS+, then backed up to that image instead of the bare share...